Should I conduct multiple chi-square tests or make multiple logistic regression?
So, I have a datasets of bacteria, and I have 1 independent variable (source of isolation) with 3 possible locations. My other variables are resistance to a lot of antimicrobials (all of them are binary, either 0 or 1). I want to discover if the isolation source plays a role in the resistances. Should I do a lot of logistic regression models? (I was doing this, because I can use odds ratios).
But I've also seen people use a lot of chi-square tests to test wether the resistance and isolation source are related.
what are differences between these approaches? is there a better one?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You likely want to fit a single model with all the variables of interest.  From there, the software will likely be able to give you the odds ratios of interest, which will be adjusted for the other terms in the model... Logistic regression and chi-square test of association can be identical, or slightly different, depending on how the hypothesis tests are conducted.  ... Also, the odds ratio could be calculated directly from a simple contingency table; you don't need to use logistic regression just to get an odds ratio.
